# Recursive observable

Tags: rxjs, reactivex

I'm working with RxJs and I have to make a polling mechanism to retrieve updates from a server.

I need to make a request every second, parse the updates, emit it and remember its id, because I need it to request the next pack of updates like `getUpdate(lastId + 1)`.

The first part is easy so I just use `interval` with `mergeMap`

```
let lastId = 0
const updates = Rx.Observable.interval(1000)
    .map(() => lastId)
    .mergeMap((offset) => getUpdates(offset + 1))
```

I'm collecting identifiers like this:

```
updates.pluck('update_id').scan(Math.max, 0).subscribe(val => lastId = val)
```

But this solution isn't pure reactive and I'm looking for the way to omit the usage of "global" variable.

How can I improve the code while still being able to return observable containing just updates to the caller?

UPD.

The server response for getUpdates(id) looks like this:

```
[
  { update_id: 1, payload: { ... } },
  { update_id: 3, payload: { ... } },
  { update_id: 2, payload: { ... } }
]
```

It may contain 0 to Infinity updates in any order

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this? Note that this is an infinite stream since there is no condition to abort; you didn't give one.

```js
// Just returns the ID as the update_id.
const fakeResponse = id => {
  return [{ update_id: id }];
};

// Fakes the actual HTTP call with a network delay.
const getUpdates = id => Rx.Observable.of(null).delay(250).map(() => fakeResponse(id));

// Start with update_id = 0, then recursively call with the last
// returned ID incremented by 1.
// The actual emissions on this stream will be the full server responses.
const updates$ = getUpdates(0)
  .expand(response => Rx.Observable.of(null)
    .delay(1000)
    .switchMap(() => {
      const highestId = Math.max(...response.map(update => update.update_id));
      return getUpdates(highestId + 1);
    })
  )

updates$.take(5).subscribe(console.log);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.6/Rx.js"></script>
```

To define the termination of the stream, you probably want to hook into the `switchMap` at the end; use whatever property of `response` to conditionally return `Observable.empty()` instead of calling `getUpdates` again.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Your solution works fine, if fakeResponse always return single value, but it can return a list.

for example: getUpdates(0) => [ 0, 1, 2 ], then I should request getUpdates(3) => [3, 4], then getUpdates(5) => [5, 6, 7, 8, 9] etc.

Comment: @Elessar.perm Then please provide a full example of your scenario. You haven't specified what the response of `getUpdates` looks like. You'll need to help us help you here.

Comment: How does `update_id` fit into this? Does `getUpdates()` return an array of objects in which each has `update_id`?

Comment: @Elessar.perm I've added a `Math.max` to my answer which I think is equivalent to the code you've shown originally.

Comment: the server returns a list of updates since id I gave. So, I basically pass the id of last update I received in order to get every update after it.

Comment: Again, please provide an actual response from the server. We can either talk about 'update_id`s or about a conceptualized question of returning an array of numbers; we can't mix both.

Comment: @Elessar.perm You've updated your question. I've updated my answer. :-)

Comment: @IngoBürk Hi, I have a scenario somewhat similar to this, but where I need to fetch more data depending on the result of a `scan`.  So I have the same setup as above but place my `scan` after the `expand`, then `takeUntil`.  Would that setup work?

Comment: I'd recommend asking a new question where you can give details about your usecase including your code.

Comment: @IngoBürk Yes, you're right.  But in your solution above, is there any way we could stop the observer when the subscriber stops reading?  Ie no more calls to `getUpdates` after the 5 takes? I think this might be referred to as "backpressure"?  The setup above would be perfect for my scenario (algorithm asking for more data until saturated), as long as the observer does not continue asking for data when the algorithm is done.

Comment: @JørgenTvedt When the subscriber stops reading, i.e, unsubscribes, the observable is terminated (that's just how observables work). Backpressure would be if the subscriber takes longer to process a single update than the time in between updates.